# With babel, why is it not recommended to place title commands before \begin{document}?

Tags: titles, babel

From the [KOMA-Script manual](https://mirror.truenetwork.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#page.296):

> The following commands only define the contents of the title.
> Therefore they must be used before `\maketitle`.  It is, however, not
> necessary and, when using the `babel` package not recommended, to include
> these in the preamble before `\begin{document}` (see [[BB13]](https://mirror.truenetwork.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf)).

However, I failed to find anything relevant in the Babel manual.

What is the reason for that recommendation? Is it still relevant?

Comment: Because depending on the language `babel` makes certain characters active, but that happens only at `\begin{document}`, so if you use any of the `babel` shorthands in the `\title` or `\author` or ... then they only apply after `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

babel shorthands don't work in the preamble. So this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\title{Gr"u"se}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

But nowadays this isn't so relevant anymore. I wouldn't use shorthands here, but simply input the title as `\title{Grüße}` and this works fine in the preamble (and I normally add the title in the preamble).

Comment: So, unless I use `babel` shorthands, I'm fine?

Comment: Yes, and even with shorthands you could do it, you only would have to activate the shorthand first.

Comment: I didn't even know they existed.